# How to retrieve UserID pass it to SharedPreferences?

Tags: php

I am connected to a PHP file that has a query on it. Now I need to know how do I retrieve de user ID Session and pass it to PHP to do the query anda only show table data from the user who does the login.

Config.java( Where I start doing the shared preferences)

```
//Keys for email and password as defined in our $_POST['key'] in login.php
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
public static final String KEY_ID = "id_utilizador";


//If server response is equal to this that means login is successful
public static final String LOGIN_SUCCESS = "success";

//Keys for Sharedpreferences
//This would be the name of our shared preferences
public static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "myloginapp";

//This would be used to store the email of current logged in user
public static final String EMAIL_SHARED_PREF = "email";

//This would be used to store the id of current logged in user
public static final String ID_SHARED_PREF = "id_utilizador";

//We will use this to store the boolean in sharedpreference to track user is loggedin or not
public static final String LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF = "loggedin";
```

PHP File from Login

```
<?php 

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        //Getting values 
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $id = $_POST['id_utilizador'];

        //Creating sql query
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Utilizadores WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";

        //importing dbConnect.php script 
        require_once('connection.php');

        //executing query
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        //fetching result
        $check = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        //if we got some result 
        if(isset($check)){
            //displaying success 
            echo "success";
        }else{
            //displaying failure
            echo "failure";
        }
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
```

PHP file that contains the query I want to use ( I want to had costs to a specific session userId.

```
<?php
class Historico {

    private $db;
    private $connection;

    function __construct() {
        $this ->db = new DB_Connection();
        $this ->connection = $this->db->getConnection();
    }

    public function guardar_historico($custos){
        $query = "insert into Custoss (custos) values ( '$custos')";
        $inserted = mysqli_query($this -> connection, $query);
        if($inserted == 1 ){
            $json['success'] = 'Custos guardado';
        }else{
            $json['error'] = 'Custos nao guardado';
        }
        echo json_encode($json);
        mysqli_close($this->connection);
    }

}


$historico = new Historico();
if(isset($_POST['custos'])) {
    $custos = $_POST['custos'];

    if(!empty($custos)){
        $historico-> guardar_historico($custos);

    }else{
        echo json_encode("you must type both inputs");
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Ouch you are storing plain text password PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: You say _how do I retrieve the user ID Session_ Do you mean you want to use the SESSION or not

Comment: I want to use the Session, I am connecting the Database from my Android App to my website and I need some way to make them comunicate. I need to give PHP the userID session from Android in order to to the query 
 $query = "insert into Custoss (custos,id_User) values ( '$custos,??')";

Comment: @RiggsFolly can u help me?